# Wallet get's disconnected from next.js solana application

Tags: reactjs, next.js, solana, anchor-solana, phantom-wallet

I have followed a YouTube tutorial to create a solana application, all my code works fine and the wallet gets connected successfull, but when I refresh the page the wallet gets disconnected and the function getWallet returns nothing (connected = false and the PublicKey is null)
here's my walletConnectionProvider:

```
import React, { FC, useMemo } from 'react';
import { ConnectionProvider, WalletProvider } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
import { WalletAdapterNetwork } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-base';
import {
    GlowWalletAdapter,
    PhantomWalletAdapter,
    SlopeWalletAdapter,
    SolflareWalletAdapter,
    SolletExtensionWalletAdapter,
    SolletWalletAdapter,
    TorusWalletAdapter,
} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets';
import {
    WalletModalProvider,
    WalletDisconnectButton,
    WalletMultiButton
} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui';
import { clusterApiUrl } from '@solana/web3.js';

require('@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui/styles.css');

export const WalletConnectionProvider = ({children}) => {
    const network = WalletAdapterNetwork.Devnet;

    const endpoint = useMemo(() => clusterApiUrl(network), [network]);

    const wallets = useMemo(
        () => [
            new PhantomWalletAdapter(),
            new GlowWalletAdapter(),
            new SlopeWalletAdapter(),
            new SolflareWalletAdapter({ network }),
            new TorusWalletAdapter(),
        ],
        [network]
    );

    return (
        <ConnectionProvider endpoint={endpoint}>
            <WalletProvider wallets={wallets} autoConnect>
                <WalletModalProvider>
                    {children}
                </WalletModalProvider>
            </WalletProvider>
        </ConnectionProvider>
    );
};

export default WalletConnectionProvider
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add AutoConnectProvider, create a file called AutoConnectProvider and add this code

```
import { useLocalStorage } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
import { createContext, FC, ReactNode, useContext } from 'react';

export interface AutoConnectContextState {
    autoConnect: boolean;
    setAutoConnect(autoConnect: boolean): void;
}

export const AutoConnectContext = createContext<AutoConnectContextState>({} as AutoConnectContextState);

export function useAutoConnect(): AutoConnectContextState {
    return useContext(AutoConnectContext);
}

export const AutoConnectProvider: FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }:any) => {
    // TODO: fix auto connect to actual reconnect on refresh/other.
    // TODO: make switch/slider settings
    // const [autoConnect, setAutoConnect] = useLocalStorage('autoConnect', false);
    const [autoConnect, setAutoConnect] = useLocalStorage('autoConnect', true);

    return (
        <AutoConnectContext.Provider value={{ autoConnect, setAutoConnect }}>{children}</AutoConnectContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

then in whichever file you have your WalletContext wrap it with the AutoContextProvider

```
export const ContextProvider: FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <AutoConnectProvider>
            <WalletContextProvider>{children}</WalletContextProvider>
        </AutoConnectProvider>
    )
}
```

Hopw this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also specify the autoconnect attribute on the WalletProvider component to automatically attempt to reconnect a user wallet upon a page refresh.

```
import { ConnectionProvider, WalletProvider } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react'

<WalletProvider wallets={wallets} autoconnect>
  <WalletModalProvider>
    <App />
  </WalletModalProvider>
</WalletProvider>
```

Comment: the boolean should actually be `autoConnect`